# Removing caption and subcaption from tikzposter

Tags: subcaption, tikzposter

I am fairly new to the `tikzposter` class. I would like to have figures in a subfigure format but without any subcaptions (i.e. (a), (b), (c), etc.) and captions.

Option 1: This gives me the right structure in terms of desired bottom alignment but also the subcaptions I do not want.

```
\begin{tikzfigure}[]
    \subcaptionbox{}{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.125\textwidth{fig1.pdf}
    }
    \subcaptionbox{}{
        \includegraphics[width=0.125\textwidth{fig2.pdf}
    }
\end{tikzfigure}
```

Option 2: Subcaptions are effectively removed but the alignment is off since my figures vary in size. I want them to be bottom aligned.

```
\begin{tikzfigure}
    \minipage{0.0375\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig1.pdf}
    \endminipage
    \minipage{0.0375\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig2.pdf}
    \endminipage
\end{tikzfigure}
```

- Is there a way to remove all captions and subcaptions while enforcing bottom alignment using `tikzposter`?

Comment: Probably you can make use of `valign=b`(available if you add `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` to your premable).

Comment: I noticed 5 minutes ago that it actually works by adding `\minipage[b]{0.0375\textwidth}`. Thank you for your suggestion though.

Comment: Actually, you don't need the minipage either.  Just adjust the width in `\includegraphics`, and maybe throw in some `\hfil`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@leandriis basically answered the question in a comment above. I added `[b]` to the `minipage` and voila:

```
\begin{tikzfigure}
    \minipage[b]{0.0375\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig1.pdf}
    \endminipage
    \minipage[b]{0.0375\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig2.pdf}
    \endminipage
\end{tikzfigure}
```

Thank you, @leandriis!